# How to exit less follow mode without exiting less when xargs is used?

Tags: xargs, less, tcsh, interrupts

```
ls -rt *.log | tail -1 | xargs less +GF
```

I use this command to `tail -f` my logs, but when I `ctrl+c` to exit follow mode, it quits `less` too.

I think it is caused by `xargs`, because if you just `less <file>`, then `shift+F` to follow it, `ctrl+c` does not quit less.

Answer (score 2):

Using follow mode when `less` is in a pipeline is not very useful, because pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> exits the whole pipeline. Moreover using `+F` eliminates need for `+G`.

In your case you can do:

```
less +F $(ls -rt *.log | tail -1)
```

which will follow the most recent log file only. You can also do:

```
less +F $(ls -t *.log)
```

which feeds all log files to `less` and follows the first (i.e. the most recent) one. In this case, after exiting the follow mode, you can inspect other files without exiting `less`.

Comment: In fact any pipeline generating file names can go in the subshell.

My use case is extracting one or several log directories from a file, then appending the rest of the standard path to the logs.

Answer (score 0):

In newer `less` versions (since 581, released on 18 Apr 2021 for general use), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to abort the `follow` command (`+F`), which does not abort other programs in the pipeline (`xargs` in this case).